# How to change the color of the status bar in a codenameone android app?

Tags: java, android, codenameone, android-statusbar

I would like to change the color of the status bar to match my app background, how can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible by placing a colors.xml file under the CN1 project `<project>/native/android` directory with the following example content:

```
<resources>
   <color name="colorPrimary">#ffffc003</color>
   <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffffc003</color>
   <color name="colorAccent">#ff009486</color>
</resources>
```

Where in this case the colorPrimaryDark is the color you would like to color the status bar

Comment: That's a highly useful information you shared. Thanks

Comment: The last 6 digits is the actual color code and not the first 6. If I want my statusbar to have red `ff0000` background, the code should be `#ffff0000` and not `ff000003`

Comment: right, the first 2 digits is the alpha value of the color

Comment: `<color name="textColorPrimary">#ffffffff</color>` can also be added to set the color of the text in the status bar

Comment: great.. colorPrimaryDark  is for status bar and what are colorPrimary & colorAccent for?