# Overflow menu not showing on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: codenameone

I'm facing a strange issue that the overflow menu does not show up on a Samsung Galaxy S4 device. I'm using the default Android action bar (i.e., I add the commands directly to the form). I didn't explicitly define/change the `commandBehavior` theme constant.

Secondly, I noticed that the action bar color which I applied via colors.xml as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904705/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-status-bar-in-a-codenameone-android-app/34904706#34904706) does not take effect (compare the attached 'expected' and actual' screenshots).

Any help will be appreciated.

**Expected (Sony Xperia Z3):**

[image: expected]

**Actual (Samsung S4):**

[image: actual]

Comment: How did you add your overflow menu items?

Comment: @Diamond: `f.addCommand(myCommand)` which effectively uses the ActionBar API on Android. And it does work on some devices but not on the Samsung S4 (and maybe others?)...

Answer (score 2):

Insert the following code in the `beforeShowForm()` method. It will add overflow menu and add your event in `actionperformed` method.

```
Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
f.setToolbar(toolbar);
toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(new Command("Test") {

  @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         // its event
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use the Toolbar API because the default look-and-feel isn't cool on Android (compared to the ActionBar) and I'm not willing to spend time styling to get the default look. Already talked with Shai about this elsewhere and he agrees that it's something to be improved. But back to my original question, the overflow menu should simply show on all Android devices where the ActionBar Android API is supported so I still think this is a bug.

Comment: I have not tested the colors.xml yet. I feel easy to use toolbar and update when you get its solution

Comment: I agree that we need to improve the default look but I'd spend that time and go with the Toolbar API. Its a better direction. The native menu in a Samsung device is hidden within the menu button so you don't get the overflow menu. The `colors.xml` only works on newer versions of Android as far as I know (Lollipop onwards).