# how can color of status bar be changed as per different forms in codenameone?

Tags: colors, codenameone, statusbar

I have gone via the beow link and it works well .
[change color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904705/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-status-bar-in-a-codenameone-android-app)

1. But there is static status color and I want to change of status bar as per the different form.
2. I want to use transparent background image as per the attached image , how can it done?[image]

[EDIT]
I have added the android.style in hint build as shown in attached image but there is no changed in status bar, is I using it correctly or not please verify it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now transparent status bar is only supported on iOS. We don't support that elsewhere.

It might work using this: [Android Completely transparent Status Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar)

But we haven't tested it and the one user who tried it didn't report success. The `android.style` build hint would allow you to inject to the `theme.xml` but I'm not sure how `android:fitsSystemWindows` can work.

Comment: I have added the android.style in hint build as shown in attached image but there is no changed in status bar, is I using it correctly or not please verify it.
Please check the image on above edited question.

Comment: How is your resulting manifest different from the one generated by the native sample? If you use include source can you customize the manifest/theme to create that effect? If so what do you need to change and what build hints would you need from us?

Comment: Use include source and look within the resulting build source https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html

Comment: I have added the below style on styles.xml 
but there is no changeon status bar
<style name="TranslucentStatusBar"  
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">   
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> 
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>    
</style>
is there any things missing or any other problem?

Comment: In the native code? Did you add the android:fitsSystemWindows attribute to the main layout?

Comment: when I add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" then it goes to add at styles.xml as shown below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
        <item name="@attr/cn1Style">@style/CN1.EditText.Style</item>
    </style>
    <attr name="cn1Style" format="reference" />
    <style name="CN1.EditText.Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    </style>
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"</resources>

and there is no change on status bar

Comment: That attribute shouldn't be in the style, it should be in the native layout which in our case should be a relative layout if I remember correctly

Comment: in which attribute should i add it?

Comment: In the native sources in the relative layout tag itself