# ActionBar text color via Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I can set Android's ActionBar background color easily via this code on colors.xml

```
<resources> 
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ffffc003</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#ff009486</color>
</resources>
```

I figured I could set the text to black adding this part:

```
<color name="textColorPrimary">#ff000000</color>
```

But it has no effect, so the background is white and the text is also white.

BTW it would be nice to allow programatically change these values, so different forms could style their own action bars.

[EDIT] The first image has android.statusbar_hidden=true. The second, use colors.txt with colorPrimaryDark as white. And the third is the result I would like to have: a status bar with white background and black foreground.

[image: android.statusbar_hidden=true] [image: colors.txt set to white] [image]

Comment: Is this question related to Codename One?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can customize the action bar on CN1 putting a color.xml file under native/android folder

Comment: Is it the equivalent of the Codename One toolbar? Why are you using native code to style it? Isn’t the Codename One CSS support enought?

Comment: No, it's not the same. The action bar is where you can see thing like battery state, wifi signal, etc. That bar can't be customised with toolbar. It is explained here: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

This will only impact the color of the status bar on top but it won't have any impact if you set the status bar to transparent.

It won't impact the action bar itself which is now drawn 100% by Codename One. I would suggest setting the status bar to transparent which will be more consistent with the way iOS handles this: [how can color of status bar be changed as per different forms in codenameone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109748/how-can-color-of-status-bar-be-changed-as-per-different-forms-in-codenameone)

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear to me how I can achieve that. Should I create a styles.xml file under native/android? Do I need to include a build hint with android.style as a key and android:fitsSystemWindows as value? Or should I download the sources and tweak something there? Please, as you can see I'm lost. A step by step explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry. I included an out of date link. The build hint is `android.statusbar_hidden=true` as explained here: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly the result I was expecting. I have updated my question. Is it possible something like that on Codename One?

Comment: Try `android.hideStatusBar=true`  it might be what I'm talking about. There's a bit of duplication of logic here. One should create this effect

Comment: Yes, that hint hides the status bar. In forms where the background is dark, it's ok, but the problem remains to me, because the indicators colors are still white. Is there any way to make them black, as in the browser screenshot in my question?

Comment: That might be a bug, Google should normally detect the colors and show a contrasting color for the status bar. Can you please file an issue with a test case. We'll look into it