# Transparent status bar codename one

Tags: border, codenameone, screen, statusbar

Everything displayed on my app belongs to a BrowserComponent.

1. I have tried in every possible way that my form is behind the status bar (with transparency) and extends to the top of the screen. I couldn't
2. I have tried to completely disappear the status bar and make my form show full screen. I couldn't.
3. Finally, given up. I have tried that at least the status bar and the green header are not separated by that white line. I couldn't either.

[text](https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_customizing_the_status_bar)
`Display d = Display.getInstance(); d.setProperty("windows.StatusBar.ForegroundColor", String.valueOf(0xff0000));  // red d.setProperty("windows.StatusBar.BackgroundColor", String.valueOf(0xffffff));  // white d.setProperty("windows.StatusBar.BackgroundOpacity", String.valueOf(10));  // fully opaque`

Comment: I'm assuming this is on Android only, right? Try adding the build hint `android.hideStatusBar=true`.

Comment: Alternatively try `android.statusbar_hidden=true`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The clock disappeared, battery level, etc. But there is still a black space in its place. I need my form to fill the screen to the top. I leave you an image https://i.ibb.co/YhLThwV/pregunta.jpg

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're trying to accomplish. I have an older answer here that might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46127157/756809

Comment: Thanks! i will try it. I just need copy styles.xml in "scr"???

Comment: That answer predated the modern maven project so I'm guessing it should go into the `android/src/main/resources` directory.

Comment: I can't find that path, my project simply looks like this https://i.ibb.co/d50YmWz/Sin-t-tulo.jpg

Comment: You're using the old ant projects, I suggest migrating to the maven builds at some point. In that case just use `native/android` as mentioned in the answer there.