# Codename One - Change status bar color in Maven project

Tags: colors, codenameone, statusbar

I have an Android app that I develop using the Maven project structure.

The app has an entirely black background, only the status bar's color doesn't change to black, but continues white. The effect is quite annoying.

[image]

I have found this code snippet from a prior query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904705/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-status-bar-in-a-codenameone-android-app) :

```
 <resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ffffc003</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffffc003</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#ff009486</color>
 </resources>
```

The code should be placed into a separate `colors.xml` file, inside the /native/android directory.

I have tried this with my Maven project, but it seems to only work for the older Ant structure.

How can I change the status bar color in Maven?

Comment: I think it should be under `android/src/main/resources` for the new maven project structure.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I actually did put the file into the right directory, but changed the color value erroneously. The value for transparency had be the fist two digits, not the last .... Using #ff000000 instaed of #000000ff solved it. All pretty now ..